# Structured use of Android SQLite transactions

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I got tired of following Android-SQLite's transaction idiom, briefly documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29).

It requires too much boilerplate code, IMHO, especially when you add the obligatory null checks. So I came up with this pattern, inspired by the Objective-C library [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb):

```
// Inside the class that manages the database
interface Transaction {
    // return false to rollback
    boolean execute(SQLiteDatabase db);
}

boolean doTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
    boolean success = false;
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try {
        db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        if (db != null) {
            db.beginTransaction();

            success = transaction.execute(db);

            if (success) {
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (db != null) {
            db.endTransaction();
            db.close();
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

Usage:

```
// In a method in that same database-managing class
doTransaction(new Transaction() {
    @Override
    public boolean run(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         // ... write to db ...
         return true; // or false to rollback
    }
});
```

Of course, both the `Transaction` interface and the `doTransaction()` method can be made available to other classes.

Does this look like a good idea? There are probably complex transactions that can't use it, but so far all of my transactions fit.

Am I missing something important with this pattern, like forgetting to close something, handle exceptions, etc? Or maybe it's just not "The Java Way" or "The Android Way" of doing things?

Comment: This looks pretty neat! Sounds like a very good idea and I would use it.
As nitpick about naming, I would call the interface method `execute` instead of `run`.

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM? Eg. ActiveAndroid, DBFlow,..?
If you prefer to write your own queries I would rather go for a generic implementation rather than a callback to differentiate between transactions.

Comment: @user1281750 I'll consider the ORM option, thank you.